# how to add and remove a class from the element with scroll event - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make navbar have a "fixed-top" class when scrolling event and removing the class when it's at the top of the page.

I wrote the script below but it is not working.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cb-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    () => {
      let nav = document.getElementById('#nav');
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (window.scrollY > 1.5) {
            nav.classList.add("fixed-top");
            document.body.style.paddingTop = '70';
        }else {
          nav.classList.remove("fixed-top");
          document.body.style.paddingTop = '0';
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't invoke anonymous function in `ngAfterContentInit()`.

And I recommend:

1. Those lines of code are could be in `ngAfterContentInit` function.
2. Whether your code is working or not, it's not proper way in Angular. Try Angular way. https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/

```js
class HeaderComponent {

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    (() => {
      let nav = document.getElementById('#nav');
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (window.scrollY > 1.5) {
          nav.classList.add("fixed-top");
          document.body.style.paddingTop = '70';
        } else {
          nav.classList.remove("fixed-top");
          document.body.style.paddingTop = '0';
        }
      });
      console.log('Listner added');
    })()
  }
}

new HeaderComponent().ngAfterContentInit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Angular CDK `scrollDispatcher`, and use `Renderer2` to add/remove class.

```
this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled(100).subscribe(() => {
  // add/remove class using Renderer2 here.
})
```